# preventing div & table from stretching down

Tags: html, css

I have an html `table` inside `div`. The problem is that when I add elements to table, the size of table and div stretches to bottom, but I want the size to remain fixed and the table should become scroll-able if all entries are not visible. I have added scroll too, but the size is still stretching to bottom. Please tell what should I do?

**Code:**

```
<div class="col-sm-6" style="overflow:scroll">
                    <table id="patientsTable" class="table table-striped">
                        <c:forEach items="${patientsData}" var="pData">
                            <tr><td>${pData}</td></tr>
                        </c:forEach>
                    </table>
                </div>
```

Comment: I think [`max-height`](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/m/max-height/) can help you

Comment: If the tables only got 1 column why not use divs? and if this is bootstrap why not use table-responsive class?

Answer (score 0):

In order for **[`overflow`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/overflow)** to take effect, you additionally need to apply the respective **[`width`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/width)** (for **[`overflow-x`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/overflow-x)**) or **[`height`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/height)** (for **[`overflow-y`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/overflow-y)**).

Simply adding a `height` will allow your content to scroll vertically.

Note that if you only want vertical scrolling and not horizontal, you're looking for `overflow-y`:

```css
.col-sm-6 {
  border: 1px solid black;
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

```html
<div class="col-sm-6">
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Pellentesque sit amet nisi id sem hendrerit sagittis ut id nisl. Integer egestas arcu id congue tincidunt. Donec sit amet metus rhoncus, congue ex et, lacinia purus. Nam in nisi scelerisque, malesuada
  sapien eu, tristique quam. Aenean dapibus libero vel magna laoreet, sed ultricies lacus facilisis. Nam elit massa, congue nec gravida non, pellentesque non sem. Morbi sollicitudin sapien et arcu condimentum viverra. Ut nec purus eget orci interdum tincidunt
  a nec massa. Ut fermentum mollis rutrum. Aenean posuere justo mi, eget venenatis nibh cursus id. Donec vel nisi porttitor, sollicitudin urna nec, pharetra turpis. In sit amet odio quis mi laoreet consectetur et quis urna. Cras neque nibh, egestas in
  tincidunt eget, aliquet et nibh. In elit ipsum, pretium porta nibh at, vulputate congue purus. Sed maximus sed tortor at congue. Duis in magna vulputate, viverra nibh fermentum, tempor felis. Morbi semper ipsum magna, et lacinia elit lacinia vitae.
  Nunc dictum varius tortor. Vivamus dictum, elit vel commodo rhoncus, mi ipsum mattis mi, in pretium nunc turpis et risus. Donec luctus dolor vel ligula vehicula euismod. Phasellus ex libero, vehicula vel blandit ut, elementum in ante. In tempor neque
  ex, at tempus elit aliquam vitae. Morbi lectus lectus, finibus quis ipsum quis, maximus dapibus metus. Nullam non orci vel tortor semper porttitor vel sit amet diam. Nulla pellentesque risus sit amet magna ultricies, in euismod leo mollis. Etiam vel
  egestas diam. Suspendisse quis mi ultricies, blandit lorem id, cursus dui. Morbi rutrum dapibus quam ut tincidunt.
</div>
```

Hope this helps! :)